# issuing curl_easy_perform(handle): 7

Tags: windows-7, operating-system, plex, microsoft-media-server

I am new to using PLEX server I found a issue in plex server i tried to cast 4-5 images in repeated format but after some time it 'll stuck at some random image. When I see the Log Files of this I found 
964] INFO - [Chromecast] [MDE] Finished analysis of jpeg (jpeg)

```
  Jan 15, 2018 13:58:16.652 [6060] ERROR - Error issuing 
  curl_easy_perform(handle): 7
  Jan 15, 2018 13:58:16.652 [8292] ERROR - Error issuing 
  curl_easy_perform(handle): 7
  Jan 15, 2018 13:58:16.652 [1860] ERROR - Error issuing 
  curl_easy_perform(handle): 7
  Jan 15, 2018 13:58:16.683 [6800] INFO - [Chromecast]   canPlay: true
  Jan 15, 2018 13:58:16.730 [5728] INFO - [Chromecast]   
  canDirectPlay: true
  Jan 15, 2018 13:58:16.840 [3764] INFO - [Chromecast] [PDE] Player 
  decision
  Jan 15, 2018 13:58:16.918 [3104] INFO - [Chromecast]   Player: html
```

I didn't get why this happen so I tried to resolve this issue from last few of weeks but not able to resolve can any one help.

Comment: I guess the issue occurs because of network I got the statement like this 
an app that has a large buffer might only need ~5.4 Mbps of bandwidth to ensure smooth playback at  plex link: https://support.plex.tv/articles/227715247-server-settings-bandwidth-and-transcoding-limits/ 
hope this will a help